# Symfony Cache clear on Multipe Servers

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

In Symfony, How can I clear the cache with Port number specified ?

Example: I am running two servers

```
    1. localhost:8000
    2. localhost:9000
```

How can I clear the cache for the localhost:9000 ?

Can we specify the port number in Clear cache command like this php app\console server:run localhost:9000 ?

If I run the php app\console clear:cache. It doesn't affects the server with Port number '9000'.

Comment: According to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html you can clear cache only for specified environment. But you can create script, that would run cache:clear for all directories you have.